# MAMP mcrypt not working

Tags: php, bash, mamp

I'm currently trying to install Craft CMS which is informing me it wants 'mcrypt installed and working'. MAMP is supposed to come with it out of the box so here's what I've tried so far..

(PHP 7.1.0)

**Changing my bash profile**

```
# Use MAMP version of PHP
PHP_VERSION=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

**Homebrew mcrypt Installing on my Mac**

```
homebrew/php/php71-mcrypt
```

**Checking php.ini that MAMP is using**

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

--

```
php -m | grep mcrypt
```

Replies in the terminal with no response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating MAMP to the latest version fixed this issue. Bug in MAMP 4.0/.1